# mvn says "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" in WSL

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, wsl-2

I want to install `mvn` on Ubuntu 22.04 on WLS on Windows. I have tried and given up to use the windows binaries and am now trying to install both java and mvn directly on wsl.

I have installed corretto 17 as `.deb` with:

```bash
wget https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-17-x64-linux-jdk.deb
sudo dpkg -i amazon-corretto-17-x64-linux-jdk.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and maven with

```bash
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.4-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-maven-3.9.4-bin.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-maven-3.9.4 /opt/
```

I've added

```bash
JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/java'
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

M2_HOME='/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4'
PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

to `.profile` and `source`d it.

And `java` seems to refer to the one I just installed:

```bash
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-22 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.8.8.1 (build 17.0.8.1+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.8.8.1 (build 17.0.8.1+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ whereis -b java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java
```

similarly for mvn

```bash
$ which mvn
/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin/mvn
$ whereis -b mvn
mvn: /opt/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin/mvn /mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin/mvn
```

while a windows binary appears it is not in first place.
If I execute `mvn -version` however, it says

```bash
$ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

relevant parts of env (Path shortened and reformatted for readability:

```bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
WSLENV=
PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin
    :/usr/bin/java/bin
    :/usr/bin/java/bin
    :/usr/local/sbin
    :/usr/local/bin
    :/usr/sbin
    :/usr/bin
    :/usr/lib/wsl/lib
    :/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.1_12/bin
    :/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.8_10/bin
    :/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin
```

I have exported a modified PATH without the windows binaries, but the response to `mvn -version` stays the same.

I would like to understand what is going on here and how I can fix JAVA_HOME, or rather have mvn accept it.

Comment: Try running this in the console: `jh="$(readlink -f $(which java))";printf "JAVA_HOME should be set to %s\n" ${jh%/bin/java}`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much @g00se! I had indeed made the wrong assumption about what `JAVA_HOME` had to be set to. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll write my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the distro's default jre and jdk like this:`sudo apt install default-jre` and `sudo apt install default-jdk` and see if that helps.